# web application design interacting with server hardware

Tags: perl, shell, jakarta-ee, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I am presently maintaining an web application managing several server hardware. This application is written in Struts and UI is quite good. But middle part is full of bash scripts and perl scripts. I would like to redesign the same. But i am not sure which languages should be used. Presently my shell scripts are calling our properitory software exes , gather information , parse through shell, perl and store in db. can someone suggest better design. These shell scripts are called by model layer. Suggestion on better design is appreciated.

thanks,
nuslch

Comment: Well, if the front-end is written in Java, why not implement the middle-end in Java as well?

Comment: As for the language part: use the general purpose language that you like best and that has the libs you need. It does not get any better than that.